# Port Forwarding On DLINK 512

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I am configuring my router to forward port `8080` or `8444` to a computer acting as a web server. My computer is well set up and I can access the hosted site via its IP address 10.*.*.121. The IP address of my router is 10.*.*.10. I am connected on the same router and I have set up the router configuration like this.

[image]

I can ping my router and my web server well. My router configuration site is port `80` and is shown as 'open' with `nmap` command. If I do an `nmap` command on `8080`or `8444` however, I find the ports are listed as filtered. I have tried changing the enable checkbox and times but I get the same result.
Is there a configuration I am missing?

---

Result of `nmap` on the router
[image]

Comment: Port 80 is open on your router because that's how it serves up the admin interface you've posted here, via webpage/webserver.  You need to check if it's open from outside your network, not inside.

Comment: yap @Radhil. thats exactly the case. Now, how do i open other ports 8080, 8444 and any other i want?

Comment: Scan the WAN port on the router, not the LAN.  If you don't have another device to do it with, there are websites that will check it for you (canyouseeme.org is the one I'm familiar with offhand).

Comment: If you see the banner it is clearly stated what the router will do: _... allows you to define a single **public port** on your router for redirection to an internal LAN IP Address and port..._. You need to point to your [public IP](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) and the port 8080 should show you your internal server. You do know that this **will expose your server to the internet**, right?

Comment: @JorgeValentini thanks for your comment. yes i do understand. Am setting up the server locally so i can connect to it whenever i am connected to the router. I want to just forwad the port of the router

Comment: @Radhil, my public ip is quite hidden. I want to connect to the webserver by calling the router 10.*.*.10:8443 and it loads up the website on the server 10.*.*.121:80. This router wont be connected to the internet.

Comment: And you have tried connecting to the public IP (not 10.x.x.10) and it didn't work? followed the recommendation from @Radhil? that was a good one.

Comment: @Lucem Then the public WAN port is not what you're trying to forward, and this config screen won't do what you want at all.  I'm not entirely certain why you'd want to do LAN port forwarding to a device on the same network you're on, but a majority of basic home routers would not support that function.

Comment: @JorgeValentini 10.*.*.10 is my router and uses the port 80 which makes sense since its the webpage to configure the router.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer now that we have more detail.

From your comment

> I want to connect to the webserver by calling the router 10.*.*.10:8443 and it loads up the website on the server 10.*.*.121:80. This router wont be connected to the internet.

What you want is technically port forwarding, but is a very obscure usage of it.  The majority of port forwarding done on home routers is Destination NAT, which allows the public IP of the router to be translated into a local private address.  What you are looking for is to translate your private destination IP into another private destination IP.  I've heard this called a port redirect in some applications.  Unfortunately, most home-use routers will not support that kind of translation; their port forwarding UIs are only set up to allow a fixed WAN IP to LAN IP translation.

It's possible a non-stock firmware like OpenWRT may be able to do what you want, but you would have to check on those capabilities, and look for a port forwarding that you can specifically set the original destination IP you are looking for on, instead of one that assumes the public IP.  This of course carries the risk of completely crashing and bricking your router if done improperly.

Comment: Yap, its port forwarding. here's an example of what am doing. This is the same router that i am using, http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2596515/port-forwarding-working-dlink-512.html
Am not going to access throught the internet however. His works however.
Here is his configuration. http://www.screencast.com/t/YIGpmrtg

Comment: @Lucem - you're missing the point. That link describes forwarding a port on a public internet IP. You want to forward a port on private internal IP. Where on your setting page can you specify on what IP you're forwarding? You can't, the router assumes you mean the WAN. This *might* work if you set a separate static network on your WAN port and connect there. It will not work on your LAN ports.

Comment: Okay, my WAN is static now.
Btw how comes the router ports 8444, 8443 are filtered?

Comment: "That link describes forwarding a port on a public internet IP." yes, after successfully forwading locally. Here - 
"I can access webcam when I'm on my home network."

So my case is to get to accessing the port on home network. 
If i go to 10.*.*.121:8443 it goes well which is the same as 127.0.0.1:8443 on the webserver. 
Can you create a chat please so we can reduce the comments?

Comment: @Lucem - at the moment, I cannot.  And you don't need port forwarding to access anything on a network you're already on, which you've just proven.

Comment: Yes, i do understand however the configuration is required to achieve some capabilities am testing out. I will look into this as per your advice and hopefully get a solution